# Android bluetooth, sending objects

Tags: android, bluetooth

The problem I'm facing is that the `BluetoothSocket` class only has a getOutputStream(). However, I need access to an ObjectOutputStream in order to perform the writeObject method necessary to serialize an object. How do I access the ObjectOutputStream from a BluetoothSocket? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the output stream you can send whatever you want so you just figure out what in the Object you want to send and do that -- most Objects are supposed to have some serialize or write Object method but you are supposed to override it to do what you need